# Relevancy search with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, sql-like

Whats the best way to go around doing this?

I have columns: track_name, artist_name, album_name

I want all columns to be matched against the search query. and some flexibility while matching.

mysql like is too strict, even with %XXX%. It matches the string as a whole, not the parts.

Comment: Using "%xxx%" is best for relevancy search. Can you give a example for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: LIKE '%XXX%' will match on a text: "this statement is true if I don't browse xxx movies"  what you actually wanted to achieve?

Comment: Lets say i searched the following: "artist's name - track name".

mysql statement should be triggered by both the artist's name @ artist_name & the track name @ track_name

Answer (score 2):

Your MySQL query could have several `OR` clauses, searching for each space-delimited word entered by the user.  For example, a user search for "Queens of the Stoneage" may be represented in SQL as `SELECT * FROM songs WHERE artist_name LIKE "%Queens%" OR artist_name LIKE "Stoneage"`.

However, that could be undesirable because `LIKE` searches which start with an `%` are inefficient and could be terribly slow on a large database.

Though I can't speak to the performance implications, you should have a look at [natural language full-text searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).  It's probably the most effective solution you'll find:

`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE MATCH(track_name, artist_name, album_name) AGAINST('Queens of the Stoneage' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);`

Some PHP functions do exist for determining the similarity of strings of text, but keeping this work in the database will probably be most efficient (and less frustrating):

- [levenshtein()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)
- [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)
- [soundex()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your application. What I understood from your comment is that you need to implement some logic operator like "and", "or" and "not" in your program. It's not only about fancy algorithm like fulltext index or longest common substring like this mysql match query. But I can be wrong.